# How to change JAVAX-WS Endpoint binding to SOAP 1.2?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, java-metro-framework

I'm publishing a test WS implementation using `Endpoint.publish()` for consumption in Visual Studio. According to [the documentation](http://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/docs/endpoint.html) the default SOAP binding is `1.1` and it is possible to change the bindings, but I can't figure out specifically how to change the binding to `1.2`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With JAX-WS 2.x you can either enable SOAP 1.2 via config file or via Java 5 annotation. See [here](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#users-guide-soap-1-2) ([original, now broken link](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.1.5/docs/soap12.html)) for more details.

Comment: java.net is closed now and no replacement is online. Is there an example ?

Comment: You can use this: @BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING) on SEI impl class. I'm not sure what is the config property.

Comment: Fixed the link, the resources seem up again at javaee.github.io.

Answer (score 2):

Since the current answer is not valid and the links are broken

By Class Annotation

```
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

By Code configuration

```
JaxWsClientFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsClientFactoryBean();
...
factory.setBindingId(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
```

By xml configuration

```
<binding name="headwig">
  <wsoap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="weave">
      <wsoap12:operation soapAction="" style="documment"/>
      <input name="grain">
        <wsoap12:body .../>
        <wsoap12:header message="QName" part="partName"
                       use="literal|encoded"
                        encodingStyle="encodingURI"
                        namespace="namespaceURI" />
      </input>
...
</binding>
```