# How does JEE decide whether to implement a SOAP service using SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

How does JEE decide whether to implement a SOAP service using SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2?  Is there setting somewhere in the EAR (annotation, XML config), or is it just dependent on the container itself?

Is there any way to tell whether a service has been implemented using SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2?

Comment: On the way to tell check this answer [Can a WSDL indicate the SOAP version (1.1 or 1.2) of the web service?
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968668/7221628)

Comment: And heres the answer on enabling 1.2 - but note, it may not be good to do it as some warn it's fairly "new" in the programming sense of things and you might be limiting the clients that can utilize your service [How to change JAVAX-WS Endpoint binding to SOAP 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823164/7221628)